# usecase of serial and parallel middleware validator (pre or post) of mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

We have serial as well as parallel pre and post validator. But can someone explain the scenarios when to use serial and parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I think serial middleware will validate first then do the mongoose operation.